# How accurate is iPhone GPS (in radius)?

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.3

i want to know how accurate our gps on iphone 4/4S because my new project is using gps for tracking something. i mean accurate is about meter. I have search other question like mine but i don't have the answer. Is it possible to track radius just say for 1 meter? how long accuracy that the gps iphone 4/4s have (in minimum)? 10 meter? how about 1 meter? can it track for 1 meter radius? oh again, my next project for my company is outdoor application. I know i can test it by myself but it more quick to get the answer from here. thank you.

Comment: http://www.gps.gov/systems/gps/performance/accuracy/ Will give you some basic information on commercial/residential gps systems, I know the iPhone for instance also makes use of IP addresses to gauge location, along with phone signal strength to each phone mast which has a fixed and therefore known location. You'll have to do some research yourself in this area for more details however :)

Comment: In practice currently you will never get 1 meter accuracy. Also note that gps accuracy can vary on different iPhone models as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621309/accuracy-of-iphone-gps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is: No, it's not accurate down to 1m.

In some cases though it is, but don't count on it. In an urban landscape I've sometimes been displaced by about 20m. but it seems like all devices gets the same displacement, so you can detect if they are close or not.

Edit: I should say that I have worked a lot with the location services on the iphone, so I'm absolutely sure of this answer.

Comment: thank you, i will report to my boss, he will dissapointed with the answer. 20 meters? how about 10 meters? um... some of my friends said if you turn on the wifi, sometimes it gets wrong coordinate that can be some displace radius, is that right?

Comment: Apple devices can get positioning aided by wifi hotspots, this should make it more precise. This is a way apple implemented location services in devices without gps.

Answer (score 2):

I have tested the 4S using the standard GPS test of positioning the unit over a known point (survey point - 1 cm accuracy) for a specific period of time. This 30 minute continuous test was done in Tucson, AZ (good GPS territory) versus New York City (tall buildings and further north) using GPS Photo-Link. So we typically look for 10 meter accuracy which means that 92% to 97% of the points are within 10 meters NSEW of the known point. The iPhone failed the first  test so I tossed the results and stopped testing it. I am waiting for WAAS on phones to see phones improve GPS but I think most phone companies are going to throw their money into making the camera better.

Answer (score 1):

Well, may be you can set the accuracy you want like

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
locationManager.distanceFilter = 10; 
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

For more information please refer [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html)
Hope this help you. good luck.

Comment: i know, i can using distanceFilter at 10 meters, but i mean in here is minimal radius that gps can track. what i see in apple documentation, they put 10 meters as short distance. i just want to know how accurate is gps iphone. i haven't yet try it so i'd better ask it first, maybe some of you already tried it. 1 meter perhaps?

Comment: refer the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515158/iphone-gps-accuracy) and [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424387/how-accurate-is-the-gps-on-the-iphone-4)