# Accuracy(?) of iPhone GPS

Tags: iphone, gps

Can anyone explain to me why 2 recent iPhones (an X and an Xr) would show wildly different "horizontal accuracy" reading? The two phones were near each other (a few meters) for several hours and were running the same software, which showed ~4.8 meters on the Xr and ~30 meters on the X.

Not a one time thing - happens consistently.

I am beta-testing a tracking app that consistently gives readings in the area of 5 meters on a 5s, a 6+ and my Xr, but this one X is an outrider (and produces really bad tracks).

I'm thinking the X's GPS is broken but that's a bit self-serving.

Comment: Are you sure you use the same setting in the phone? (high accuracy location [so more battery use]).

Comment: All the settings that I could find are the same. In particular, both phones have "Precise Location" turned on for my app. I am wondering if there is some setting somewhere which defeats precise location.

Answer (score 0):

Those two phones were released in different years (X is from 2017 and XR from 2018) and probably they use a different GPS chip. Different iPhones (and especially from different years) can have different GPS chips and accuracy. I observed similar quite large differences between iPhone 7 and iPhone SE 2020.

I do not know what chips those exact iPhones that you mentioned in your question use, but for example I found that iPhone 5S was using Qualcomm WTR1605L chip for GPS and iPhone 7 was using Broadcom BCM47734 chip for GPS.

According to technical specification on Apple website iPhone XR has "GPS/GNSS" and iPhone X has "Assisted GPS, GLONASS, Galileo, and QZSS" so apparently there are some differences in used technologies there. I'm not sure what all those names exactly mean but I think that can explain different results between those two phones and basically "GPS/GNSS" is better than "Assisted GPS, GLONASS, Galileo, and QZSS".

Also similarly I can confirm that according to Apple website phones from my tests that is iPhone SE 2020 has "GPS/GNSS" and iPhone 7 has "Assisted GPS, GLONASS, Galileo i QZSS" and I got similar results as you did with XR and X.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your consideration but I am now convinced that the GPS was broken on my friend's iPhone X. But we'll never know for sure since she traded it in on a more recent model without ever taking it in for servicing, whereupon I heard no more complaints.

The app I was testing, "HikeTracker", has now been released and works fine for quite a few users with various iPhone models from 5s on up - it's hard to see how a change of technologies could have been the culprit since it hasn't been a problem for phones released before or after the change.